# Azure Active Directory: Add Service Principal to Directory Readers Role with PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, service-principal

- The command `(Get-AzureRmADUser -Mail $user).Id` in a Azure PowerShell Task returned null when running on a self-hosted agent in VSTS
- The problem was that the Service Principal needs to have the permission to read from the Active Directory

How can I give the the Service Principal the correct permissions to read from the Azure Active Directory?

Comment: this is not a question, you could better have this as a blog post!

Comment: What is so bad about having this here? It is based on a question (why (Get-AzureRmADUser -Mail $user).Id returns null) and directly provides the answer. Don't know what your problem actually is.

Comment: If you vote down please provide a reason why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Prerequisites

- Check if you have the proper permissions to get the object id from a Service Principal
- Check if you have the proper permissions to add the Service Principal to the "Directory Readers" role in the Azure Active Directory tenant (-> Admin)

## Steps

- Install the Azure AD Module via `Install-Module AzureAD` [1]
- Connect to the Azure Active Directory

  - `Connect-AzureAD`
- Get the Id of the "Directory Readers" role

  - `$roleId = (Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | where-object {$_.DisplayName -eq "Directory Readers"}).Objectid`
- Get the Service Principal Object ID

  - `$spObjectId = (Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "spName").ObjectId`

    - This of course only works if the result includes only one ObjectId
    - This is not the ObjectId of the application registered in the Azure Active Directory
- Add service principal to the "Directory Readers" role

  - `Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $roleId -RefObjectId $spObjectId`
- Check if SP is assigned to the Directory Readers role

  - `Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $roleId | Where-Object {$_.ObjectId -eq $spObjectId}`
- If you want to remove the Service Principal from the role at a later stage

  - `Remove-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $roleId -MemberId $spObjectId`

See also [2]

## Resources

[1] [Install Azure AD Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0#installing-the-azure-ad-module)

[2] [Using a Service Principal to connect to a directory in PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/signing-in-service-principal?view=azureadps-2.0)

Comment: do we have an azure cli version of those commands

Comment: not CLI but the graph API is available. which can be used using `az rest` 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/custom-assign-graph#example-1-create-a-role-assignment-between-a-user-and-a-role-definition