# How To Use Service principal To Assign A Role To Another Service Principal

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines

How can I give a service principal access to assign a role to a resource it created?

---

Here's the scenario.

I...

- Created an Azure DevOps pipeline
- Created a Service Connection (which creates a service principal and grants it `Contributor` access to the entire subscription).
- Created a pipeline task `AzureCLI@1` using the service connection
- Executed `az group create …` - **SUCCESS** - made a resource group!
- Executed `az group deployment create …` - **SUCCESS** - deployed some stuff!

  - ^-- (Unless I do any role assignments as part of my ARM template)
- Executed `az role assignment create …` - **FAILURE**

`ERROR: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.`

---

I tried making the service principal `Owner` instead of `Contributor`.  No difference.

This made me understand (kinda) why: [Azure Service principal insufficient permissions to manage other service principals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52285608/azure-service-principal-insufficient-permissions-to-manage-other-service-princip)

Which lead me here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-rm-endpoint?view=azure-devops#failed-to-assign-contributor-role

---

But I'm a little stuck.  I **think** I'm supposed to grant my service principal some sort of role within active directory so that it's allowed to manage role assignments.

I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/roles-delegate-by-task#roles-and-administrators

Based on that, it seems I should give my service principal `Privileged role administrator` access.  *scary*.

Then I found this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles

Because I wanted to limit this service principal to only be able to flex the active directory powers **within a single subscription**, which seems to be possible in the `AssignableScopes` property.

---

But two things are giving me pause, which brings me here.

1)  I'm relatively unfamiliar with what I'm doing, and I'm tossing around big scary terms like `Administrator` ***shudder***.  Time to consult some experts!

2)  This seems complex.  The task I'm performing seems like it should **not** be complex.  I'm just trying to deploy AKS and a Container Registry in an Azure Pipeline and give AKS access to the registry.  Which is what all the docs say to do (albeit at the commandline, not in a pipeline).

---

So, should I really be creating a custom role just for the subscription which gives `Privileged role administrator` type privileges assignable only to the subscription, then granting my service principal that role?

Or... How do I do this?

---

EDIT:

I did try creating a custom role with action `Microsoft.Authorization/write`.  It failed with this error: `'Microsoft.Authorization/write' does not match any of the actions supported by the providers.`

But I succeeded in creating one with action `Microsoft.Authorization/*/write` as well as `Microsoft.Authorization/*`

My .json definition looks like:

```
{
  "Name": "...", "Description": "...", "IsCustom": true,
  "Actions": [ "Microsoft.Authorization/*" ],
  "AssignableScopes": [
    "/subscriptions/[subscriptionid]"
  ]
}
```

After assigning the role to the service principal, it still failed with insufficient access.  I logged in locally via `az login --service-principal`, tried to use my new powers, and got this message:

`The client '...' with object id '...' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/.../Microsoft.Authorization/read' over scope '/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/.../.../providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.`

---

EDIT:  SOLUTION

```
{
  "Name": "...", "Description": "...", "IsCustom": true,
  "Actions": [ 
    "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/read",
    "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write"
  ],
  "AssignableScopes": [
    "/subscriptions/[subscriptionid]"
  ]
}
```

This works with `az role definition create`.

The service principal also needs to be a Directory Reader, unless you specify the role assignment by object-id.  [Azure Active Directory: Add Service Principal to Directory Readers Role with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51759015/azure-active-directory-add-service-principal-to-directory-readers-role-with-pow)

It can be assigned to the service principal, and when executing `az` commands as that service principal, it succeeds in creating role assignments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to grant it `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write` custom permission or the built-in role of owner. scope would be subscription if you want to be able to do that for every resource group\resource in the subscription or you can be more granular (say specific resource groups or even resources).

your custom role link is the right way to create custom roles.

edit: OP needed to add `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/read` as well, for me it works without it.

Comment: The built-in "Owner" role does not work.  It only works for users, not service principals.  I've edited my answer to show the results of trying to grant it Microsoft.Authorization/write permissions (failed)

Comment: right, because it failed to read permissions. you need to assign that permission as well if you want to actually read those. and it doesnt matter if its a user or a service principal from the RBAC standpoint

Comment: I assigned Microsoft.Authorization/* and it didn't work.  I assigned Microsoft.Authorization/*/read and Microsoft.Authorization/*/write and it didn't work.  I created it with az ad sp create-for-rbac --role Owner and it didn't work.

Comment: I create it using az ad sp create-for-rbac and assign it using az role assignments create --assignee [appId from prev command] and login using az login --service-principal [appId from prev command]

Comment: just try `az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp" --role owner` and it would work fine and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor) you can check difference between owner and contributor. I dont know what you are doing wrong exactly, but for me it works with just `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write`

Comment: Fixed.  Using your recently edited 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write', plus 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/read' permissions (and a fixed scope).  If you update your answer to mention /read, I'll mark it as accepted